# How do I LoadClass() from outside project build?

Tags: java, loadlibrary

I'm trying to create an exploit, I want to load a class from outside the netbeans project, of a subclassed cash register, which should have been made final.

I can load the LegitClass fine from within the original package `badclassloader`, with:

```
claz = "badclassloader.LegitClass"
loadClass = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(claz);
(LegitClass)loadClass.newInstance();
```

Now I want to load the `MalClass` which lives in another project and package 'Package Mal'

1. How do I get the `Mal.MalClass` into the path for the `LoadClass()` method to find?

I tried the following:

```
    private void loadLibrary() {
    if (library != null) {
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {
                System.loadLibrary("Path/to/Project/mal.jar");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but firstly I got `Directory separator should not appear in library name` So that clearly isn't it, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something considerable here.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` is used for loading external, native, libraries, not Jars

Comment: Okay so I need a make a library from my Mal Project?

Comment: No, you need to use a custom class loader to load the Jar and then use that to load the classes from it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new, custom class loader...

```
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(
        new URL[]{new File("Path/to/Project/mal.jar").toURI().toURL()}
    );
```

Load the class from the class loader...

```
Class clazz = cl.loadClass("Mal.MalClass");
```

Create a new instance of the class...

```
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

Now.  You have a problem.  Unless the `Class` you've just loaded implements a `interface` which is common to both projects, you won't be able to resolve the instance of the `Class` to an actual type, as the type would be unknown at compile time.  Instead, you would be forced to use reflection, which is never pretty...

Comment: MAGIC, I've got all the interface magic working already.
thank you again!

Comment: Is the AccessController stuff required?

Comment: It would only be requireed if you are operating in a environment with a `SecutiryManager` installed (like Applets for example)

Comment: If I produced a Library instead of Jar could I use the example I had?

Comment: Remember, a library (in this context) is a natively compiled code and is used by the JNI portion of the API.  I has (little) to do with Java code