# Add classes to project after compile time

Tags: java, javassist

I have a project which can contain a lot of modules. Each module is stored in a single `class` file. But when I deliver the software to the customers, it is not clear which modules they will need in the future.

Is it possible to deliver `class` NewClass to my customer and he can call a method from it without changing the code of the existing program?

He could type the name of the `class` in a field, so the program would know which `class` to use. And all the methods names are same in all the added `class`es.

I guess it could work with Javassist, but I did not find a good tutorial for it.

I would like to call method m1() from NewClass.

```
class NewClass implements MyModule {
  @Override
  public void m1() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to explore the concept of "custom class loading".  In the past, I developed a plugin architecture which was basically a `Jar` file, which contained a "plugin" descriptor and each "entry point" would then adhere to a set of different `interface`s, so it was easy to load and make it available to the overall application

Comment: Would the [`Class::forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) method solve your problem?

Comment: [For a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819278/how-do-i-loadclass-from-outside-project-build/21819525#21819525)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Dynamically choosing subclass/object to create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924311/java-dynamically-choosing-subclass-object-to-create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. What you're looking for is [the reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

For example:

```
String cName = askUserForClass();
assert cName.equals("com.foo.schreiber.PriceyModule");
Class<?> moduleClass = Class.forName(cName);
MyModule mm = (MyModule) moduleClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

and now you have a variable of type MyModule. You can just invoke `m1` on this, assuming `m1` is in `MyModule` and `MyModule` is in the base version (that's how you should be setting this up).

Note, of course, that `com.foo.schreiber.PriceyModule` does need to be on the classpath of the JVM for this to work. If it is not, this answer is going to grow about 3 pages worth, to set up a class loader, set up loading parentages so that you share the `MyModule` definition, and a whole lotta code to reliably find the jar or whatever it might be that is the source of the extra module. So, you know. Would be a lot simpler if you can just ensure it's on the classpath. As long as its in the jar, that'll be the case.

Comment: While it will work, reflection  won't scale well and will be a consistent source of issues (IMHO)

Comment: It's not in the jar, because I will provide it to a later time, but thank you very much for the solution